# Google Tag Manager event prevents HTML5 download attribute

Tags: html, google-tag-manager

I have an event set up to record downloads of PDFs in GTM for a site. I now want to use the HTML5 download="test.pdf" attribute

```
<a href="/Factsheet.pdf" download="Factsheet.pdf" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

Without the Tag Manager script included on the page the click downloads the pdf directly in my browser (desired behavior) but when GTM script is added the click results in a new tab opening with the PDF.

My GTM Event firing rule is configured as per the image below.

Any ideas where I might be going wrong?[image: GTM]

Comment: The image is quite hard to see; I had to zoom in too many times to see it. Can you repost it? I haven't tested the download attribute in GTM yet, but at least based on the image, it looks like you are using an "{{element url}} matches Regex \.pdf" rule, which requires that the url of the clicked element equals the string ".pdf", and nothing else. You'll need to modify the Regex to include the other parts of the element url like the file name and just the extension, or use "contains .pdf" instead or something.

Comment: Ok, just tried an experiment on my site, and it everything seems to be working. Event is fired even configured with the same rule as yours. What problems are you seeing? Is the event not firing? What are you expecting to see with the download attribute? I'm not seeing any difference with that, and I actually don't expect to as I am not using that attribute for anything.

Comment: To remove one source of error you could delete the target attribute, which is unnecessary at best (you only set targ=_blank when you want a new tab/window).

Comment: What browsers are you testing?

Comment: I understand your problem now I think. At least this is the problem I saw, and it may have nothing to do with the GTM tags. When the GTM container is on the site, clicking on the link with the download attribute still opens the PDF, rather than downloading it. When the GTM container is NOT on the site (or commented out), clicking on the link with the download attribute just downloads the file, like it should.

Comment: Yes @nyuen you are correct. I want the download attribute to behave the way it should and download directly. It does this until I include the tag manager script on my page. With GTM script included it changes behaviour and opens the pdf in a new tab (not what I want).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @EikePierstorff but that results in the pdf opening in current tab not downloading

Comment: Hi,
Was this issue resolved? We are also having a similar issue. 
Below tag is getting generated by JSONToCsvService(library) and appended to body tag.

<a href="data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%2CMessages%20Sent%2C%20" download="Sample.csv">Analytics Report</a>

When we click on this element it should popup a Save -as dialog in same window and pre populate the file name ( in above case Sample.csv)

when there is no Google Tag manager then file name is shown properly in Save-as dialog. When Google Tag manager is enabled file get downloaded but file name is not auto populated.